# mongodb schema for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am working on an internal app to do host/service discovery. The type of data I am storing looks like:

```
IP Address: 10.40.10.6
DNS Name: wiki-internal.domain.com
1st open port:
port 80 open|close
open port banner:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 08:58:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And so on. My first thought is to just put it all in one document with a string that identifies what the data is like "port","80". After initial data collection I realized that there was a lot of data duplication because web server banners and such will often get reused. Also out of 8400 machines with ssh there are only 6 different banners.

Is there a better way to do the design the database with references so certain banners only get created once. Performance is a big issue since the database size will double in the next year. If possible I would like to keep historical banner information for trending.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's flexible schema allows you to match the needs of your application.  While we often talk about denormalizing for speed, you certainly can normalize to reduce redundancy and storage costs. From your initial analysis and concern over database size, it seems clear that factoring out the redundancy fits your application, in this case, store banners separately and reference them with small ints for _ids, etc.

So do what you need for your application, and store your data in MongoDB in the form that matches the needs of your application.